MongoDB MongoOperations :: Query to search for the keyword value inside the sub-document without using the fieldName in the query Criteria
I have Java Spring boot application with MongoDB database. I'm trying to search for the keyword inside the collection with sub-document using the MongoOperations Query Criteria, without specifying the fieldname in the sub-document.
Basically, I want to do full sub-document search for the value across all fields and return the List of document objects.
I have tried multiple options using Query Criteria but northig works. Sample code is as below.
Code 1:
    var query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("excelDataList")
    .elemMatch(Criteria.where("")
    .elemMatch(Criteria.where("data")
    .regex(keyword, "i"))));
    List<ExcelInfo> excelInfoList = this.mongoOperations.find(query,ExcelInfo.class);

Code 2:
    var query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("excelDataList")
    .elemMatch(Criteria.where("")
    .elemMatch(Criteria.where("data")
    .elemMatch(Criteria.where("$**")
    .regex(keyword, "i")))));
    List<ExcelInfo> excelInfoList = this.mongoOperations.find(query,ExcelInfo.class);

Please suggest how we can achieve sub-document search across all fields in the collection.
Sample Message:-
search Keyword in the message:- RatesSystem
[{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "66f31e018038282a16ff2e75"
  },
  "region": "EUROPE",
  "system": "FX",
  "route": "Inbound",
  "feedName": "FXRATES",
  "upStreamDownStreamSystem": "RatesSystem",
  "versionNo": "1",
  "excelName": "RATES_Files.xlsx",
  "excelDataList": [
    [
      {
        "data": {
          "Countries": "Australia",
          "Files": "Australia_Rates_Files.txt",
          "Source": "RatesSystem"
        },
         "sheetName": "FXRATES"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

